# Function that accepts every type of argument

Tags: c++, variables

Let's say I want to create a function that `cout`s the value I pass it, but I don't know whether it is an `int`, or a `string`, or….

So something like:

```
void print(info) {
   cout << info;
}

print(5);
print("text");
```

Comment: Soon, you could technically write that as `auto print = [](const auto &info) {cout << info;};` I don't think the function version is going to be in C++14, but that would have reduced it to something like `[]print(const auto &info) {cout << info;}`.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void print( const T& info)
{
   std::cout << info ;
}
```

Comment: It is to notice that this function is wide open to *any* type at all, even user defined. Therefore it is your job to make sure that `info` can be an argument of `std::ostream::operator<<`.

Comment: @Jeffrey good point, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a function template.

```
template<typename Arg>
void print(const Arg& arg)
{
    std::cout << arg;
}
```

Comment: Why `Arg&&`, by the way?

Comment: function template is the correct term. @minitech, that is the perfect forwarding idiom, but `const &` would be more appropriate here because the argument is not modified and there's no `std::forward`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Oops. quite right! Thanks for pointing that out'

Answer (score 2):

We could use the template to finish this.

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << t <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    print(12);
    print("123456");
}
```